# Select DropDown Menu Item [WEBBROWSER]

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

HTML Code

```
<label class="hideContent" for="select_price_category">Select a price category</label>
<select id="price_category" style="margin-left:20px;" name="price_category">
<option price="1500" value="1">£300</option>
<option price="995" value="2">£200</option>
<option price="655" value="3">£300</option>
</select>
```

how do you do this

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? (And `for="select_price_category"` should be `for="price_category"`.)

Comment: @bfrohs just an automate thing that selects a dropdown box (just like clicking on it) for education use. i have seen someone do this for one, but unsure how to do it for this                                       Dim element As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("BirthMonth")
    Dim month As HtmlElement = element.GetElementsByTagName("option").Cast(Of HtmlElement).First(Function(el) el.GetAttribute("value") = "05")
    month.SetAttribute("selected", "true")
End Sub

Comment: Why is this tagged `visual-c++`?

Comment: i have no idea can anybody help or not........

Answer (score 0):

That should be within a form element. Take a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp